# Not able to see Nmap XML output on browser properly

Tags: nmap

I installed Nmap 'nmap-7.70-setup.exe' today. I performed a sample scan with -oX option. Once the XML output is generated, I tried to launch on my browser. However, it seems it is showing like a raw data. I am unable to see in a good format that I usually did. Requesting for your help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolve the problem by myself. My old Nmap was installed at C:\Program Files\ whereas my new Nmap is installed at C:\Program Files (x86). Hence the new nmap.xsl file is placed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap. That is I was unable to view my old Nmap XML files properly.
Solution:
Step-1: Check your " path on existing Nmap XML output.
Step-2: Check where is the Nmap installed.
Step-3: The path mentioned on Step-1 must be same with the path of Step-2